# openpyxl conditonal formatting based on cell

Tags: python, openpyxl, conditional-formatting

I'm using an openpyxl conditonal_formatting of CellIs type, so I can do:

```
rule = openpyxl.formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['3'], fill=fill)
```

But I can't seem to make formula anything other than a constant... if I try to put in 'Q1' it just never does anything...

Comment: This is more of a request about how the conditional formatting rules work in Excel than anything else.

Comment: No, in was a question about why I was being an idiot, and comparing things to Q1 instead of B{row} + Q1...  I happened to be testing with a case that just never triggered the condition... B-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `fill` defined as? This works fine for me:

```
red_fill = PatternFill(start_color='EE1111', end_color='EE1111', fill_type='solid')
ws.conditional_formatting.add('B1:B5', CellIsRule(operator='greaterThan',
                                                  formula=['B3'], fill=red_fill))
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: FWIW I've found that `Expression` rules are the most useful and easiest to work with when writing your own rules.